# Can't upload photo using paper clip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, file-upload

I used paper clip in my web application, I use this to make a new product:

```
<% semantic_form_for @product do |f| %>  
  <% f.inputs do %>  
    <%= f.input :title %>  
    <%= f.input :price %>  
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>


    <%= f.input :category , :include_blank => false %>  
  <% end %>  
  <%= f.buttons %>  
<% end %>
```

And this to show product:

```
<% semantic_form_for @product do |f| %>  
<%= image_tag @product.photo.url%>

  <% f.inputs do %>  
    <%= f.input :title %>  
    <%= f.input :price %>  
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>

    <%= f.input :category , :include_blank => false %>  
  <% end %>  
  <%= f.buttons %>  
<% end %>
```

And his is my product.rb:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :price
  validates_numericality_of :price
  validates_uniqueness_of :title

  has_attached_file :photo
  attr_accessible :name, :category_id, :price, :title, :photo
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :order_items

end
```

But after I upload the photo, it show my image path like this :

> http://localhost:3000/photos/original/missing.png

It seems that it can't upload the photo with this error:

> ```
> No route matches "/photos/original/missing.png" with
> ```
>
> {:method=>:get}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what `semantic_form_for` is, but with regular `form_for`, you have to explicitly say it's a multipart form.

```
<% form_for(@thing, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  ....
```

If you don't do this, the contents of your file upload fields won't be transmitted to the server. It's a HTML *thing* ;)

Comment: I seee, I am missing the :html => {:multipart => true}, wt is it for??

html => {:multipart => true}

Answer (score 0):

I think you paste the image into public/images folder in your rails application.And give the path like in your browser "/images/missing.png".

And your index will be